# Android Studio Gradle not working

Tags: gradle, android-studio

I tried lot of different solutions but none of them is working and still getting error

```
Gradle 'MyApplication' project refresh failed
    Error:Error:No cached version listing for com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.+ available for offline mode.
```

I tried:

```
Uninstall/install android studio
Remove .gradle folder from user directory
Change 0.12 to 1.12. in gradle properties
Enable Use local gradle distribution in gradle settings.
```

any suggestions how can I fix this.

I also tried various solutions mentioned in stackoverflow but none of them is working.

Comment: Switch to an online mode?

Comment: switching to online mode getting me this error Error:(1, 0) Plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found.

Comment: Either you have network problems, or there's some other issue with your build file. If you post the full error output from a build as well as your build files, it may help.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed the issue, please follow these steps

1. Goto "File->Settings" in the settings window choose "Gradle" and under the "Globle Gradle Settings" unchecked the "offline work" check box and click "Apply" & "ok".
2. Do Gradle sync or restart the IDE.
3. Once Gradle build is success, can check the "offline work" again.