# ionic build Android | error: No installed build tools found. Please install the Android build tools

Tags: android, cordova, ubuntu, ionic-framework

When I run **ionic build android** command in root of ionic project, I am getting this error:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - Where: Script '/home/javad/Desktop/javadApp/platforms/android/CordovaLib/cordova.gradle'
>     line: 64
> - What went wrong: A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
>
>   > No installed build tools found. Please install the Android build tools version 19.1.0 or higher.
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

```
javad@javad:~/Desktop/javadApp$ ionic build android
Running command: /home/javad/Desktop/javadApp/hooks/after_prepare/010_add_platform_class.js /home/javad/Desktop/javadApp
add to body class: platform-android
Running command: /home/javad/Desktop/javadApp/platforms/android/cordova/build 
ANDROID_HOME=/opt/android-sdk
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/default-java
Running: /home/javad/Desktop/javadApp/platforms/android/gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b /home/javad/Desktop/javadApp/platforms/android/build.gradle -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script '/home/javad/Desktop/javadApp/platforms/android/CordovaLib/cordova.gradle' line: 64

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
> No installed build tools found. Please install the Android build tools version 19.1.0 or higher.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 1.564 secs

/home/javad/Desktop/javadApp/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error code 1 for command: /home/javad/Desktop/javadApp/platforms/android/gradlew with args: cdvBuildDebug,-b,/home/javad/Desktop/javadApp/platforms/android/build.gradle,-Dorg.gradle.daemon=true
ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: /home/javad/Desktop/javadApp/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 8
You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
Error: /home/javad/Desktop/javadApp/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 8
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:134:23)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:743:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:810:5)
```

in ~/.profile i have:

> export PATH=$PATH:/opt/android-sdk/tools
>
> export PATH=$PATH:/opt/android-sdk/platform-tools
>
> export PATH=$PATH:/opt/node/bin
>
> export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/default-java
>
> export ANDROID_HOME=/opt/android-sdk

$PATH is:

> /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/opt/android-sdk/tools:/opt/android-sdk/platform-tools:/opt/node/bin

**Important issue:**

**in file:**
/home/javad/Desktop/javadApp/platforms/android/CordovaLib/cordova.gradle | **line 38**:

```
String[] getAvailableBuildTools() {
    def buildToolsDir = new File(getAndroidSdkDir(), "build-tools")
    buildToolsDir.list()
        .findAll { it ==~ /[0-9.]+/ }
        .sort { a, b -> compareVersions(b, a) }
}
```

just returned **/opt/android-sdk/build-tools**  !!!

in **/opt/android-sdk/build-tools** folder i have:

**android-5.1** folder that extract from:
https://dl.google.com/android/repository/build-tools_r22-linux.zip

Comment: Its Working for me check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38660955/ionic-cordova-in-android-studio-no-installed-build-tools-found

Answer (score 72):

I fix this by downloading sdk package called **platform-tools** and **buid-tools** using `sdkmanager`. You can use **sdkmanager.exe** or if you are using [SDK CLI](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#command-tools), go to `~\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\bin` and run this command:

```
sdkmanager "platform-tools" "platforms;android-26"
```

or

```
sdkmanager "build-tools;27.0.3"
```

or both

After that you should be able to run `ionic cordova run android` or `ionic build android`.

Note: globalize `sdkmanager` command by adding `~\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools` and `~\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\bin` to your environment variable.

Comment: Don't forget to run cmd as Administrator to avoid errors.
I faced Warning: "Failed to read or create install properties file" error

Comment: Thank you, this was an essential step for me in the build process.

Comment: opened terminal within the bin folder: says 

sdkmanager: command not found

Comment: @LasLemieux please check if you install the SDK CLI properly. If u are using windows, there should have a file named sdkmanage.exe.

Comment: This worked for me but I had to add --sdk_root option to prevent the following error:
Observed package id 'tools' in inconsistent location '/opt/cmdline-tools/tools' (Expected '/opt/tools')

Answer (score 65):

**For me running these three commands fix the issue on my Mac:**

```
export ANDROID_HOME=~/Library/Android/sdk
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=~/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=${PATH}:${ANDROID_HOME}/tools
export PATH=${PATH}:${ANDROID_HOME}/platform-tools
```

**For ease of copying here's one-liner**

```
export ANDROID_HOME=~/Library/Android/sdk && export PATH=${PATH}:${ANDROID_HOME}/tools && export PATH=${PATH}:${ANDROID_HOME}/platform-tools && export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=~/Library/Android/sdk
```

**To add Permanently**

Follow these steps:

1. Open the .bash_profile file in your home directory (for example, /Users/your-user-name/.bash_profile) in a text editor.
2. Add `export PATH="The above exports here"` to the last line of the file, where your-dir is the directory you want to add.
3. Save the `.bash_profile` or `.zshrc` file.
4. Restart your terminal. Or run `source ~/.bash_profile` or `source ~/.zshrc` depending on your terminal settings.

[Adding to bash process for different systems](https://gist.github.com/nex3/c395b2f8fd4b02068be37c961301caa7)

Comment: This helps me every time, but as soon as I close terminal or restart the mac, I need to do this again

Comment: This worked for me.  @Forza if you add it to your ~/.bash_profile it will work everytime.

Comment: I mistakenly had those PATH subdirectories appended to my ANDROID_HOME variable. Once I cleaned this up, it worked!

Comment: How do you make it that you dont have to re rerun the command every time you restart the terminal?

Comment: I tried that but it doest stick I have to do it every time I open terminal.

Comment: Can you please go through https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22465332/setting-path-environment-variable-in-osx-permanently and let me know if any of that works for you I'll add that to answer here as it's currently working for me @RossRawlins

Comment: To permanently install in mac paste this in both files:
'nano  ~/.zshrc'  and  'touch . bash_profile'

Comment: ANDROID_HOME is deprecated, use ANDROID_SDK_ROOT instead

Comment: Thank you @manuman94 just updated my answer can you please have a look if it's fine

Comment: Yes! That should work! But I would remove the old ANDROID_HOME as its use is discouraged: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/variables#envar Greetings!

Comment: The `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` pointing to the SDK we are using on Android Studio is the trick. Having that environment variable fixes the problem of not knowing where to look for the build tools.

Answer (score 31):

You are missing android SDK tools. Please try the following:

```
android list sdk --all
android update sdk -u -a -t <package no.>
```

Where `<package no.>` is `1,2,3,n` and

```
-u (--no-ui)  # Headless mode
-a (--all)    # Includes all packages (also obsolete ones)
-t (--filter) # Filter by package index
```

Comment: It throwing me ```Filter 19 not supported```

Comment: 2018 update: Use `-t android-27` for version 27 etc.

Comment: 2021 update:
`The "android" command is deprecated.` `For manual SDK, AVD, and project management, please use Android Studio.` `For command-line tools, use tools/bin/sdkmanager and tools/bin/avdmanager`

Answer (score 22):

as the error says ***'No installed build tools found'***
it means that

1 : It really really really did not found build tools

2 : To make him find build tools you need to define these paths correctly

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/vijay/Software/android-sdk-macosx
export PATH=${PATH}:/Users/vijay/Software/android-sdk-macosx/tools
export PATH=${PATH}:/Users/vijay/Software/android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools
```

3 : **IMPORTANT IMPORTANT** as soon as you set environmental variables you need to reload evnironmental variables.

```
//For ubuntu
$source .bashrc 

//For macos
$source .bash_profile
```

4 : **Then check in terminal**

```
$printenv ANDROID_HOME
$printenv PATH
```

Note : if you did not find your changes in printenv then restart the pc and try again printenv PATH, printenv ANDROID_HOME .There is also command to reload environmental variables .

**4 : then open terminal and write HALF TEXT '$and'  and hit tab. On hitting tab you should see full '$android' name.this verifys all paths are correct**

5 : write $android in terminal and hit enter

Answer (score 18):

> Please install the Android build tools version 19.1.0 or higher.

The following commands can update Android SDK on Ubuntu quickly and fix the above error:

```
android list sdk --all
android update sdk -u -a -t 19
android update sdk -u -a -t 20
```

Comment: Filter 19 and Filter 20 is not supported

Comment: same here @Skizo-ozᴉʞS

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS, please did you find the solution to it?

Answer (score 18):

I fix the error  by changing the  **ANDROID_HOME** to
**C:\Users\Gebru\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk** from wrong previous directory.

Comment: This worked for me. I didn't have `ANDROID_HOME` set and Cordova assumed it was at `/usr/lib/android-sdk` which was incorrect

Comment: I have the same, except I stopped before /Sdk. Seems anything wrong with that line breaks it

Comment: I had `C:\Users\alexa\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms` instead of `C:\Users\alexa\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk`

Comment: -- Relaunch Android Studio, Relaunch the terminal, Relaunch `cordova build`.

Answer (score 9):

2018

```
The "android" command is deprecated.
```

try

```
sdkmanager "build-tools;27.0.3"
```

This work for me, as #Fadhil said

Answer (score 7):

I know this doesn't look related, especially given the error message, but I fixed this by installing a newer version of the Android SDK Build tools.

Answer (score 6):

In my case, the Enviroument Variable ANDROID_HOME was pointed to wrong (old) directory. I reallocated to correct one. In my case

ANDROID_HOME=F:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk

Comment: Thanks was it, I had it pointed to android studio which was suggested somewhere else.

Answer (score 6):

For me, the problem was that ANDROID_HOME was pointing to an old Android SDK path. After installing Android Studio, I had to update ~/.bash_profile accordingly for MAC (El Capitan)

export ANDROID_HOME="/Users/corneliusparkin/Library/Android/sdk"

Remember to re-start terminal or run this command after updating ~/.bash_profile

source ~/.bash_profile

Answer (score 5):

FOR WINDOW: I have faced this type of issue. But after exploring it solved in my case. I am using window 10. just follow few steps below:

1. download Android SKD Manager for windows. https://developer.android.com/studio at the
   end of this page. It is zip file. after extracting it will show tools directory.
2. Go to drive C:\ create new folder 'android-sdk'. copy tools folder and past in
   C:\android-sdk
3. open command prompt as Administrator. Go to cd " c:\android-sdk\tools\bin ".
   sdkmanager will be show here. type
   skdmanager, it will show like this
   [=======================================] 100% Computing updates...
4. after that type "sdkmanager platform-tools" it will create platform-tools directory
   in C:\android-sdk
5. Now set System environment variables: right click on PC select
   properties. system settings will popup. click on > Environment Variables. Environment
   Variables will popup.
6. At this window System variables as like this. C:\android-sdk\platform-tools and
   C:\android-sdk\tools\bin
7. run command to build tools  sdkmanager "build-tools;27.0.3"

   Also make sure java path is defined. I hope it will solve problem.

Comment: In point no. 3 you have spelling mistake "skdmanager" It should be `sdkmanager`

Answer (score 5):

I Search this problem for days.... I hope it will be usefull

FINAL SOLUTION:
(I assume that you have installed Oracle-JDK and ANDROID)

open /etc/environment with

```
 sudo nano /etc/environment


PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/shoniisra/Android/Sdk/tools:/home/shoniisra/Android/Sdk/platform-tools:/home/shoniisra/Android/Sdk/build-tools:/home/shoniisra/Android/Sdk:/home/shoniisra/android-studio/bin"
JAVA_HOME="/home/shoniisra/java/jdk1.8.0_231"
ANDROID_HOME="/home/shoniisra/Android/Sdk/build-tools/29.0.2"
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT="/home/shoniisra/Android/Sdk"
ANT_HOME="/home/shoniisra/ant/apache-ant-1.9.14"
```

Save and exit (CTRL+o CTRL+X)

Reload file `source /etc/environment`

If you recently installed Android you should accept some licences

```
cd ~/Android/Sdk/tools/bin/
```

Execute sdkmanager:

```
./sdkmanager --licenses
```

Then Accept all, and Finally generate your APK

```
cd {yourproyect}
sudo ionic cordova build android
```

Answer (score 4):

Type android on your command line and install "Android SDK Build-tools"

Comment: In my case, you were right. I forgot to install the Android SDK Build tools from the SDK Manager. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I have solved this issue by following steps:

1. Go to cordova.gradle file
   (platform/android/cordovaLib/cordova.gradle)
2. Search for getAndroidSdkDir() method
3. Now simply replace System.getenv("ANDROID_HOME") with your real Android SDK path

Answer (score 2):

In build.gradle script it checks if build-tools version is lower than maxVersion from Gradle configuration.
So in my case, I had environment SDK vars set, but my version was higher than allowed.

```
def highestBuildToolsVersion = buildToolsDirContents
    .collect { new Version(it) }
    // Invalid inputs will be handled as 0.0.0
    .findAll { it.isHigherThan('0.0.0') && it.isLowerThan(maxVersion) }
    .max()
```

Comment: That was the problem in my case, you just have to go to Android SDK Manager --> SDK Tools, then check "Show Package Details" and install missing versions.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I tried all the solutions on this page, but what worked for me was installing the EXACT version of build-tools requested. In my case, I had a later version installed(33.0.0), but in order to make it work I had to download an older one 30.0.3.

Answer (score 1):

This problem I solved with the following detail, somehow the android SDK manage installed all the dependencies and necessary files, but forget this `` `templates` `` files where is found templates> gradle> wrapper. This set of files is missing.

[image: Screenshot]

Path  in mac 
`/Users/giogio/Library/Android/sdk/tools/templates`

Answer (score 1):

I added `<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="19" />` 
to my `conf.xml` and the build was successful.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was that ANDROID_HOME was pointing to `~/Library/Android/` for some reason.
The correct path is `~/Library/Android/sdk`

Answer (score 1):

Open Command Prompt Check for ANDROID_HOME path using SET ANDROID_HOME, if not set then set using below command.

```
 SET ANDROID_HOME="C:\Users\VenkateshMogili\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk"
```

OR
open system environment variables and create new variable as

```
 Variable Name: ANDROID_HOME
 Variable Value: C:\Users\VenkateshMogili\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
```

and open cordova.gradle file (***/platforms/android/CordovaLib/cordova.gradle***) and search for **getAndroidSdkDir()** method and Replace the ANDROID_HOME path (**"C:/Users/VenkateshMogili/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk"**) instead of **System.getenv("ANDROID_HOME")**

If license problem arises then type below command by opening the command prompt in **C:\Users\VenkateshMogili\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\bin**

```
  sdkmanager "build-tools;27.0.3"  //<-that will create build-tools folder and licenses folder.
```

It works for me.

Comment: Isn't the fifth line of the log OP posted already showing that `ANDROID_HOME` is set (to `/opt/android-sdk`)?

Comment: Once check in your Home Directory, mostly it could be present in Home

/home/username/Android/sdk

Try to set that if it found. 

paste the below line at the end of the .bashrc file(in home directory)

export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Android/Sdk

Answer (score 0):

This works for me! be careful with the new java versions because they cause error, check that you have everything installed and in your specific directory,

> I did not use openJDK

```
export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-jdk" \
&& export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH \
&& export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Android/Sdk \
&& export PATH=${PATH}:${ANDROID_HOME}/tools \
&& export PATH=${PATH}:${ANDROID_HOME}/platform-tools \
&& export GRADLE_HOME=/usr/share/java/gradle/bin/gradle \
export PATH=$PATH:$GRADLE_HOME/bin
```

Linux 4.14.39-1-MANJARO #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed May 2 19:03:39 UTC 2018 x86_64 GNU/Linux

[image: see the screenshot in my shell]

Answer (score 0):

The solution for this question is here
https://docops.ca.com/devtest-solutions/8-0-2/en/installing/setting-up-the-mobile-testing-environment/preinstallation-steps-for-mobile-testing/

Please follow this steps, and solve your problem.

The Android SDK package contains a component called compile tools. The mobile test requires at least version 19.0.1, 19.1.0 or 20.0.0.

If these versions are not installed with your ADT package, you may receive an error message when creating a mobile asset in the DevTest Workstation:

Answer (score 0):

Mac IOS

Edit ~/.bash_profile by using vi or other shell editor

```
vi ~/.bash_profile
```

Add the following lines:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=~/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=${PATH}:~/Software/android-sdk-macosx/tools:~/Software/android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools"
```

(save the file, and exit)
load those updated env variables to the current shell env:

```
. ~/.bash_profile
```

- If from some reason you have an old version of the build tools, you can update them from the android development studio:
- Configure --> SDK Manager --> select "Android SDK Build-Tools
- Check the "Show Package details"
- review the versions of this package, update if needed

Answer (score 0):

Well Many people give their answer, some answer is same, some answer id different. I try many answer but they are did not work for me, of course I try from above answer also but did not solve my issue. And I don't know why but I have the same error even my issue solved by this [ANSWER](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27709699/9088454). I just want to write it might be helpful for someone.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried all the above solution. None works.
Until I was linked to [https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-v4-no-installed-build-tools-found/152150.](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-v4-no-installed-build-tools-found/152150)

Apparently, you must run the command as root. Sudo is not enough. You need to change to root user before you can run all the commands.

Answer (score 0):

### Warning for developers using Virtual Machines

I spent a very long time trying to resolve this issue. I tried everything in this post and many more solutions on the web. However, after many failures and going through what everyone on the web was saying I still couldn't resolve the issue on my VM - which is a Windows 10 image on VMWare Workstation.

After reviewing all the solutions and descriptions of machines/operating systems people were developing on the glaring difference in my setup was I was developing in a VM.

**Solution:** I pulled all my code onto the host machine (Windows 10 OS), reinstalled all the dependencies, and sure as heck it all worked out first go around. After a lot of research I found some warnings that Android Studio has some known issues around installing properly in some VMs. So if you were like me & tried all solutions (many times over) and nothing worked, but you're in a VM, you may need to consider building on your host (or other physical machine)

Answer (score 0):

This issue also occur if you do an upgrade to you cordova installation.

Check if your log error has something like:

```sh
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=undefined (recommended setting) <-------------
ANDROID_HOME=/{path}/android-sdk-linux (DEPRECATED)
Using Android SDK: /usr/lib/android-sdk
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)
```

In such case, just change `ANDROID_HOME` to `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` in your `~/.bashrc`
or similar config file.

Where before was:

```
export ANDROID_HOME="/{path}/android-sdk-linux"
```

Now is:

```
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT="/{path}/android-sdk-linux"
```

Don't forget source it: `$ . ~/.bashrc` after edition.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you have added android SDK paths to the environment file (.bash_profile). If you installed android studio with default path, then add the below lines to your environment file. In my case, I am using bash so I have updated the .bash_profile

```
export ANDROID_HOME=~/Library/Android/sdk
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=~/Library/Android/sdk
export ANDROID_AVD_HOME=~/.android/avd
```

Answer (score 0):

I wasted a day to resolve this issue and finally I got solution
-First I removed ionic cordova platform android
-Install ionic cordova platform android@8

That's it

Answer (score 0):

1. create a ~/.bash_profile and ~/.zshrc file.
   touch ~/.bash_profile;
   touch ~/.zshrc;
2. edit and copy/paste this in your ~/.bash_profile or ~/.zshrc file
   So, go to your file manager and show all hidden files by using Cmd+Shift+. or Cmd+>

i) Edit your .zshrc file

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8 
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/bookwarm/Library/Android/sdk
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=~/Library/Android/sdk
export ANDROID_AVD_HOME=~/.android/avd
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/{your name}/Library/Android/sdk/tools
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/{your name}/Library/Android/sdk/tools/sdkmanager
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/{your name}/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/{your name}/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/{your name}/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin
export ANDROID_NDK=/Users/{your name}/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
```

ii) Edit your .bash_profile file

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/{your name}/Library/Android/sdk
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=~/Library/Android/sdk
export ANDROID_AVD_HOME=~/.android/avd
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/{your name}/Library/Android/sdk/tools
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/{your name}/Library/Android/sdk/tools/sdkmanager
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/{your name}/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/{your name}/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/{your name}/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin
export ANDROID_NDK=/Users/{your name}/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
```

3. Save your file with file->save like you would save any regular file, after that write this in your terminal
   source ~/.bash_profile;
   source ~/.zshrc;
   Close you terminal and run your command now

Answer (score 0):

On **windows** I checked the path of the sdkmanager and switched in the terminal to:

```
cd C:\Android\android-sdk\tools\bin
```

than I ran following commands:

```
sdkmanager "platform-tools" "platforms;android-33"

sdkmanager "build-tools;33.0.0"
```

Before that I checked if Android Studio has installed the tools and if the path is correct, so the version might be different to mine. The **build-tools** and **platform-tools** are located in:

```
C:\Users\[yourUsername]\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
```

So you can check your version there.

Answer (score -1):

Go to D:Android sdk\Android SDK and click on SDK Manager and check whether Build Tools are installed or not if they are not installed then install those tools

Answer (score -1):

This is very irritating error and I wasted my almost 9 hours to solve this.

Steps to solve:

Notice **ANDROID_HOME** while you run `ionic cordova build android` command. For example in my case it was pointing to some other android sdk which I uninstalled and then it started pointing to right sdk.
**In my case I uninstalled:**

```
brew cask uninstall android-sdk
brew cask uninstall android-platform-tool
```

then I ran `ionic cordova build android`

```
> cordova build android
ANDROID_HOME=/Users/anand/Library/Android/sdk
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_172.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Then it might say "licences not accepted" then run below command:

`cd /Users/Android/sdk/tools/bin/`
then run `./sdkmanager --licenses` and
accept all with y option

Then it might say unable to download jars. Then go to platform android and build.gradle and search for buildscript, and inside that reverse the order

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
}
```