# Ionic Build failed with an exception(build tool not found)

Tags: cordova, ionic2, android-emulator, android-build

I ran this command `ionic cordova run android` but it gave this error: `build tool not found`. When I run android studio the build function runs properly without any errors. I just can't understand what to do. Even I removed the platform folder and add this but the error does not change.
I have

- Windows10
- Ionic 3.5
- node-v6.11.1-x64
- emulator: API 25

The given error is:-

```
Running command - failed!

[ERROR] Cordova encountered an error.
        You may get more insight by running the Cordova command above directly.

[ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova build android (exit code 1):

     FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
        * Where:
        Script 'E:\wamp64\www\nutricity\platforms\android\CordovaLib\cordova.gradle' line: 64

        * What went wrong:
        A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
        > No installed build tools found. Install the Android build tools version 19.1.0 or higher.

        * Try:
        Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

Comment: what is your cordova-android platform version?

Comment: Installed platforms:
  android 6.2.3

Answer (score 0):

If its says that, it means that the system:
1 : It really really really did not found build tools

2 : To make him find build tools you need to define these paths correctly

People have experience this before and possible solutions could be found here: [ionic build Android | error: No installed build tools found. Please install the Android build tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31190355/ionic-build-android-error-no-installed-build-tools-found-please-install-the)

Comment: I defined the path:- ANDROID_HOME > E:\Android\tools ; JAVA_HOME > C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111; [Now what to do]

Answer (score 0):

Solution that worked for me:

- Right click This PC(My computer)
- Click Properties
- Go to Advance System Settings
- Click Environment variables
- Inside System Variable find Path and Edit It
- Insert three 4 paths:
  SDK, Build tools, Platform tools, Platform

> (Default path if you have not changed)

- C:\Users[Your Username]\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
- C:\Users\Saddam Khan\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools
- C:\Users\Saddam Khan\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools
- C:\Users\Saddam Khan\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform