# occurred evaluating root project 'android' No installed build tools found. Install the Android build tools version 19.1.0 ionic 3

Tags: windows, angular, android-studio, apk, ionic3

i'm getting this error for building `unsigned apk` for `ionic 3`

i'm getting this `error`

> What went wrong: problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
>   No installed build tools found. Install the Android build tools
>   version 19.1.0 or higher.

i have installed `android` `studio 9.*`

**which looks like this**

[image]

**the command that i followed**

1. `ionic cordova platform rm android`
2. `cordova run android`

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ionic build Android | error: No installed build tools found. Please install the Android build tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31190355/ionic-build-android-error-no-installed-build-tools-found-please-install-the)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your Android SDK is not updated.