# Ionic build tools installed but receiving error "No installed build tools found. Install the Android build tools version 19.1.0 or higher."

Tags: android, ionic-framework, build, sdk

I am trying to build and generate an apk for my Ionic 4 application. When I attempt to do this, I am met with the following error:

```
A problem occurred evaluating project ':CordovaLib'.
[cordova]  > No installed build tools found. Install the Android build tools version 19.1.0 or higher.
```

I have looked at many other solutions on Stackoverflow for this problem and nothing has fixed my issue. I have the Android SDK and SDK tools installed through the Android Studio SDK manager.

I have ANDROID_HOME set in both my .bash-profile and Android Studio path variables. Here is what my .bash-profile file looks like, which is where I believe environmental variables are intended to be set?

```
export ANDROID_HOME=~/Users/zacharyjordan/Library/Android/sdk
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=~/Users/zacharyjordan/Library/Android/sdk

export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/tools/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/platform-tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/emulator
```

When I attempt to build my application, it doesn't even seem as if Ionic is detecting my updated ANDROID_HOME path. It lists ANDROID_HOME as ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/Caskroom/android-sdk/4333796

If anyone knows what I can do to get my app to build properly I would greatly appreciate it. No other solutions on Stackoverflow have fixed my problem thus far.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ionic build Android | error: No installed build tools found. Please install the Android build tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31190355/ionic-build-android-error-no-installed-build-tools-found-please-install-the)

Answer (score 1):

I just troubleshooted this error on a coworker's computer and the problem was an environment variable called `ANDROID_SDK_HOME` that was set to a different folder (`C:\Android` in his case). Changing that variable to match the actual sdk folder fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you get that because of your environment path is not correct.

What worked for me (Windows 10):

open **Android Studio** -> **SDK Manager** -> **SDK Tools**

☐ Hide Obsolete Packages

☑ Show Package Details

From **Android SDK Build-Tools** list

☑     29.0.3

Set the PATH for the ANDROID_HOME to YOUR_PATH\sdk

Answer (score 0):

> I have the Android SDK and SDK tools installed through the Android
>   Studio SDK manager

`SDK tools` is different than the `build tools`.

Go to SDK manager, download **build tools** `v19.1.0` or higher then error should be gone.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have Android SDK Build-Tools installed and the issue is persisting.

Comment: pls boss im dying of thirst

Comment: This might be duplicate which you should check this answer; https://stackoverflow.com/a/38659163/4409113

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve my issue with the above error by creating 2 environment variables on my OSX machine for ANDROID_HOME this essentially is the same as what you did above but for my paths. (I had not done this prior.)

After that I ran the command sdkmanager "platform-tools" in my cordova projects CLI. I had difficulties resolving this issue before using Android Studios SDK Manager but this method seemed to clear things up.

Note: If build tools cannot be found for your project. It's worth trying sdkmanager "build-tools" in your CLI.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by

```
export ANDROID_HOME=~/Android/Sdk
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26647945)

Comment: @Ritesh this is how I solved the same mroblem. Just sharing a possible solution.