# Cordova build android "no android build tools"

Tags: android, cordova

So im running into a probelm with cordova
I am running a linux machine trying to build a cordova app how ever,
When i try

```
$ Cordova build android
```

I get a the following error

> No installed build tools found. Install the Android build tools version 19.1.0 or higher.

How ever i do have it installed
And i have edit my .bashrc & .profile to reflect the changes needed for
$ANDROID_HOME

Am i missing something?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an error of the paths:

You need to define paths as:

```
vim .bashrc
```

Add the following lines:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/user/Software/Android
export PATH=${PATH}:/Users/user/Software/Android/tools
export PATH=${PATH}:/Users/user/Software/Android/platform-tools
```

Note: When you edit the environment variables you need to reload them.

```
$source .bashrc //for ubuntu

$source .bash_profile //for mac
```

Type the following command:

`$android` 
in terminal and hit enter.

If everything is working fine you can try running
`$cordova build android`

This seems to be a duplicate of the question: [questions/31190355/ionic-build-android-error-no-installed-build-tools-found-please-install-the](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31190355/ionic-build-android-error-no-installed-build-tools-found-please-install-the)