# Trying to build an android app with Cordova

Tags: java, android, git, cordova

I use Git Bash and Cordova to create phone apps, but when I try to build my app, it displays this :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPlTv.png)

I already put the PATH in environment variables.
Maybe the problem is in the .bash_profile here

**ADT_SDK="C:\sdk"
export JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231"
export PATH=$PATH:$ADT_SDK/platform-tools:$ADT_SDK/tools:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$ANT_HOME/bin**

Comment: make sure JAVA_HOME is pointing to java jdk home eg 
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191

Comment: Duplicate  of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31190355/ionic-build-android-error-no-installed-build-tools-found-please-install-the