# Why do i get this error when trying to build cordova app in Android studio

Tags: android, cordova, gradle, phonegap

I have installed the latest build-tools; 29.0.2. Still it says no build-tools installed

C:\Users\user\Downloads\android-studio-ide-\android-studio\bin\runnerw.exe C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\cordova.cmd run android
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=undefined (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk (DEPRECATED)
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app

Project evaluation failed including an error in afterEvaluate {}. Run with --stacktrace for details of the afterEvaluate {} error.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\Users\user\LagBus\platforms\android\CordovaLib\cordova.gradle' line: 68
- What went wrong:

  > Configure project :app
  >   A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
  >   No installed build tools found. Install the Android build tools version 19.1.0 or higher.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 16s
C:\Users\user\LagBus\platforms\android\gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
Project evaluation failed including an error in afterEvaluate {}. Run with --stacktrace for details of the afterEvaluate {} error.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\Users\user\LagBus\platforms\android\CordovaLib\cordova.gradle' line: 68
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

  > No installed build tools found. Install the Android build tools version 19.1.0 or higher.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 16s
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx1024M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be that you don't have the android tools configured in your PATH, so **cordova** can't find them.

So, check that, in your path you have access to the android build tools and even other Android development environment configurations.

This is an example of a problem similar to yours, and how to solve it:
According to this: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/13120

EDIT: you have your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38659163/3051976)