# Ionic Problem on Linux: No installed build tools found. Install the Android build tools version 19.1.0 or higher

Tags: android, angular, linux, bash, ionic-framework

I try to build android project from Ionic, in linux, with command:

```
ionic cordova build android
```

but i have this error:

```
"No installed build tools found. Install the Android build tools version 19.1.0 or higher."
```

In particular, I have this line of code in .bashrc:

```js
export ANDROID_HOME=/home/matteo/Android/sdk
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64
export HOME=/home/matteo
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$PATH
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
```

In Android Studio I have installed

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ionic build Android | error: No installed build tools found. Please install the Android build tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31190355/ionic-build-android-error-no-installed-build-tools-found-please-install-the)

Comment: Yes! Thanks Joel!