# All SDK build tool installed, but error showing "No installed build tools found. Install the Android build tools version 19.1.0 or higher." ionic

Tags: android-studio, ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic-native

IF I build from terminal, works fine, but when I try to build using Android Studio, error showing :
`No installed build tools found. Install the Android build tools version 19.1.0 or higher.`
Although all build tools already installed in my Android Studio

Screenshots -
[image]

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ionic build Android | error: No installed build tools found. Please install the Android build tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31190355/ionic-build-android-error-no-installed-build-tools-found-please-install-the)

Comment: From the terminal, it works fine, when I try to build from Android studio, this error occur

Comment: from 19.1.0 to 30.0.0 , All build tools already installed